# How to prevent modify library of arduino?

Tags: library

For some reasons of security, I created library for everybody to use, but I don't want people change my library, cause it make device not work. I search around but still not working. Do I need to set password for library or make it unreadable or make it can not modify or another way that you can give the direction ?

P/s: Think like a hacker, I can change library and make an attack to the server from library.

Comment: why is it a problem for you if someone changes the library and the device fails as a result?

Comment: it make device not work

Comment: @Quang, that does not answer my question ... you already said that the device may not work .... why is it your problem? ... why is it not the problem of the person that changed the library?

Comment: *it make device not work* - what device? A few more details, please.

Comment: Maybe if you provide a precompiled library for the users. Though I'm not really qualified in that field.

Comment: See my amended answer for my thoughts about your "hacker" comment.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't do that. How could a library work if it is unreadable?

If you don't want people changing it, don't publish it.

If you publish it you could put a disclaimer on it:

> If you change my library, it may stop working.

---

**(Added to question two days later)**

> P/s: Think like a hacker, I can change library and make an attack to the server from library.

Yes, but, if you distribute the original library, then someone would have to download it, change it, and then attack themselves with it!

And if your library does something to do with servers (you haven't said *what* your library does) then someone could make a similar library, and build the attack code into that. Hacking your particular one wouldn't be required.

My other issue is: If your library is a secret, that is, I can't read its source code, then I might presume that *your* library is where the hack is. At least if people get the source code they can read it and check it.

Answer (score 3):

Later versions of the IDE have the ability to use pre-compiled libraries.  This means that the end user only gets the compiled version of your library (a `.a` file) rather than the source code.

Modify your `library.properties` file to include `dot_a_linkage=true`. If you don't have a `library.properties` file you need to make sure you create your library in 1.5.x format.

Then compile your library in the normal way. This will result in a `.a` file somewhere in the build  tree which gets linked with your sketch.  You need to grab that `.a` file.

Next make a new copy of your library that has just the header file (needed for compilation) and the `.a` file (needed for linking). No `.cpp` files.

Now you in the new `library.properties` file you add `precompiled=true`.

As long as you lay out the files right it should now compile using the precompiled `.a` file.

You can read more about the `library.properties` contents [here](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/Arduino-IDE-1.5:-Library-specification).

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know that.

Comment: @NickGammon it's not something that is well documented, and not used much. I haven't used it myself, just inferred it fun the spec.

Comment: This answer should probably mention that this is only a mild deterrent, as it's relatively easy to disassemble and edit a `.a` file.

Comment: @JosephSible It's simple to extract the .o files from a .a file, yes. Less easy to disassemble those .o files back into source code, modify them, and recreate them. I'd hardly call it a "mild" deterrent.  True, anything can be reverse engineered if you're determined enough - but we're talking about an Arduino library here - with the associated level of competence that a typical Arduino user has...  I.e., a .a file is a complete mystery to them...

Answer (score -1):

Distribute your library in compiled format. The when code is compiled it's "translated" from "human readable code" to "machine code". Machine code is almost impossible to read and understand without years of experience.

There always is a possibility of decompilation. There are programs called decompilers that change any "machine code" into "human readable code". The resulting code is different then your original code, and there is nothing you can do to prevent decompilation because in the end Arduino has to have that "machine code" to know what operations to execute, and it's impossible to have it encrypterd in any way.

You can make always decompilation more troublesome. There is a procedure called "code obfuscation". You can manually, (or using a specialized code obfuscation software) make the "human readable" code no longer readable by humans. They can add extra variables, extra methods change constants to variables that are generated by completely unrelated parts of code. This will also change machine code, and make the code after decompilation much harder to understand. Unfortunately it will also complicate the machine code and make library run much slower.

Fun Fact!

There exists a competition in code obfustation https://www.ioccc.org/

And this is a valid C code that you can compile and run. https://www.ioccc.org/2014/sinon/prog.c
[image: https://www.ioccc.org/2014/sinon/prog.c]